# How can I resolve python requests package import error?

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, package

I am new to python and am having trouble getting the python requests package to run.  I have searched around for answers, but it seems that the question is most often answered with instructions on installing the requests package, which you will see I have already done.

Before I start, my specs are as follows:

OS: MacOSX Catalina 10.15.7
Shell: iTerm2 Build 3.3.12
Python Versions:
System: 2.7.16
pyenv: 3.9.0

Use Case: I am experimenting with web scraping and am attempting to write a simple program that will scrape some data from a local car dealership's website (e.g. scrape info on cars listed under $20k).

Before starting the project, I installed the requests package with the following command:

```
% pip3 install requests
```

I then opened up a vim file and wrote the following, just to ensure that the requests package was working properly:

```
import requests
URL = 'cardealerurl.com/query'
page = requests.get(URL)
```

I saved the file as carScrape.py.

Then I went beck to the shell and executed the following:

```
python carScrape.py
```

on execution, I receive the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "carScrape.py", line 1, in <module>
     import packages.requests
ImportError: No module named packages.requests
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. If more information is needed, please just let me know and I will provide whatever I can.  Thank you all so much.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by running the following commands:

```
% sudo -H pip3 uninstall pip
% python3 -m ensurepip
% pip3 install requests
```

This was after a pretty long chunk of time trying other solutions that did not work.  I also had to start a new shell to get rid of the error message.